# How do I correctly import org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:1.0.4.RELEASE?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, spring-data

My project is using org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:1.7.2.RELEASE and this requires org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:1.0.4.RELEASE which is missing from the Maven repository, I tried adding the repo in this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5894 but IntelliJ finds nothing when testing the link (https://repo.spring.io/release). I tried downloading the .jar and then installing it with

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=spring-data-keyvalue-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar -DgroupId=org.springframework.data -DartifactId=spring-data-keyvalue -Dversion=1.0.4.RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

The .jar is in the .m2/repository directory but still nothing. I'm using Gradle to build and adding `compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:1.0.4.RELEASE'` to the build.gradle file gives another error.

The full error is:

`Could not find org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:1.0.4.RELEASE.
  Required by:
      :my-project:unspecified > org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:1.7.2.RELEASE`

How do I import that library? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It requires `spring-data-keyvalue` 1.1.2 according to the pom and that is available in maven central. If that isn't the case with your setup you are overriding the version some where yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks a lot that was the solution! I added the 1.1.2 to the build.gradle and it worked! No idea why it was asking for 1.0.4.